# To confirm, Is this a type of anti-join?

Tags: sql, join

We know that an anti-join is a type of Join where we try to get unmatched rows. I am faced with the following question:

> Find the titles of all movies that have no ratings.

I've developed the following SQL query to satisfy that:

```
select Movie.title
from Movie
where Movie.mID not in (select Rating.mID from Rating)
```

I have ran into the term anti-join earlier, and I just wanted to confirm that this was indeed a anti-join. In particular this is a right anti-join.

Comment: Look here: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: That is no JOIN at all although the results might be the same with one.An anti join is select a LEFT JOIN B ON.. WHERE bcol  IS NULL

Comment: This is one way of expressing an anti-join in SQL.  Whether it is left or right . . . I'm not sure, but I would guess left.

Answer (score 0):

It is a kind of anti-join that is not really accepted as correct because  method is slow and ineffecient because you query two times. The more faster way and 'official' anti join would be:

```
SELECT
Movie.title
FROM Movie as t1
LEFT JOIN Rating as t2 ON t1.mID = t2.mID
WHERE t2.mID IS NULL
```

Comment: Wouldn't a query optimizer be able to handle the uncorrelated sub-query and therby the ineffiency would be eliminated?

Comment: I am not sure on that though, i dont have much knowledge of query optimizers and such, but i was allways thaught to use as less sub-query's as possible because subquery's would exponantially slow down the process. For a small database it would be almost nothing, but for a huge set of records it could give you some time addition

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [article](http://blog.montmere.com/2010/12/08/the-anti-join-all-values-from-table1-where-not-in-table2/):

> This is very slow and inefficient, because the RDBMS has to compare
>   each row with an entire table of values. The following is much much
>   faster, as it matches up each row once, then simply eliminates the
>   results that are not in the second table:

```
SELECT
*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: The query optimizer should be able to recognize and handle that right?